# Find words starting with user input symbol and count in which text line they are C++

Tags: c++, string, char, text-files, c++20

I have an exercise in which I need to find words in a text file starting with user input symbol. I also need to determine in which line that word is and output that in text different text file.
I managed to write code to output words starting with symbol and count word's position in text, but i cannot figure out how to count in which line that word is. Also i need to find those words which have symbols like `?` `!` etc. not only `' '`
For example if i wanna find words starting with `c` then my program finds only "cerebral, cortex, could, create" but not "construct, capable, computers" from my example input which is below my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    fstream input;
    fstream output;
    string word, line;
    char startOfWord;

    cout << "I wanna find words starting with symbol: \n";

    cin >> startOfWord;

    int lineNumber = 0;

    input.open("f.txt");
    output.open("f1.txt");

    while (!input.eof()) {

        input >> word;
        lineNumber++;
        if (word.length() > 40) {
            continue;
        }
        if (word[0] == startOfWord) {
            output << word << ' ' << lineNumber << '\n';
        }
    }

    input.close();

    output.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Example input: user wanna find words starting with `a`.

**f.txt**:

```
A Stanford University project to?construct a model 
of the cerebral cortex in silicon could help scientists 
gain a better understanding of the brain, in order to 
create more,capable.computers and advanced 
neural prosthetics.
```

Output: **f1.txt**

```
a 1
a 3
and 4
advanced 4
```

Comment: Could you include an example input and output file?

Comment: Also, which C++ version are you using? A C++20 answer will likely contain [`std::string::starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with) so if you are using something older, that'd be good to know.

Comment: @Telescope included input and output files

Comment: @TedLyngmo C++20 yes

Comment: @AnnaVolksone Great, I added that tag. I won't be around for many hours so I won't be able to write an answer, but it'll give others an idea what they can and can not use in their answers.

Comment: Use `std::getline()` to read a line at a time into a string. Use `std::stringstream` and `operator>>` to split a line into words.

Comment: @MartinYork okay will try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To point you in the right direction without completing your exercise for you, there are a few functions available to you through `std::ifstream` and `std::basic_istream`, which is the class from which `std::ifstream` inherits many of its capabilities.

```
std::ifstream::getline()
std::ifstream::get()
std::ifstream::peek()
std::ifstream::putback()
```

These functions deal with capturing entire lines of input, reading characters from an input stream, looking at characters without extracting them from a stream, and putting characters back into a stream.

All of these may be found on the [C++ Documentation site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) for `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Thank you! Will try to get this thing done! I previously used getline() for counting lines and it worked but still i got only so far - counted lines. :(

Comment: I could give you some better direction if I knew what your input file looked like. Unfortunately, using getline() and get() without any other functions like regex to search for patterns makes character comparison algorithms largely dependent on *how* text is represented in your input file. Is everything on a separate line? Are there repeating characters you can use to signify a stopping point (delimiters like ';' or ','). Maybe an example of your input file would help answer this question a little better :)

Comment: i included my input file in description "f.txt". stopping point is ' ' or '.'